# Quiero hacer un login para samba, como puedo crear un usuario para saber si puede escribir en una carpeta o no?

Tags: c#, wpf, samba

Quiero crear un login para acceder a SAMBA pero no se como hacerlo, he intentado por

> Console.WriteLine("net use \xxx.xxx.x.x /user:{usuario} {contraseña}");

y funcionar funciona pero por ejemplo si da error no puedo capturarlo por que va por consola y no se como capturar el erro.

no se si hay alguna otra forma para establecer la conexión desde WPF.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! te fijaste si habia alguna libreria en nuget?? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que he creado ha sido esta:

```
    public async Task LoginToSamba(string user, string passwd)
    {
        //creamos el proceso que funcion como un cmd
        var process = new Process();

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = @"/c" + $"NET USE {xml.getConfigFolder()} /user:{user} {passwd}",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        await Task.Run(() => { process.WaitForExit(); }); ;
        var errorID = process.StandardError.Read();
        string errorMessage;
        switch (errorID)
        {
            //-1 es que si funciono
            case -1:
                await _DialogBox.AletBox($"{user}, se ha conectado correctamente.");
                return;
            case 5:
                errorMessage = "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos.";
                break;
            case 53:
                errorMessage = "El servidor no se pudo encontrar. Es probable que no tenga conexión.";
                break;

            case 67:
                errorMessage = "El servidor no se pudo encontrar, intente cambiarlo desde conf";
                break;

            case 69:
                errorMessage = "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos.";
                break;

            case 1219:
                errorMessage = "Este ordenador ya está logeado con una cuenta, " +
                    "SAMBA no permite tener mas de una cuenta en el mismo ordenador, " +
                    "deslogeese y vuelva a intentarlo";
                break;

            default:
                errorMessage = $"Error desconocido {errorID}.\n 1-Deslogueese previamente. \n 2-vuelva a logearse.\n 3-Compruebe que tiene conexión.";
                break;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar Process para usar comandas cmd eso va también para aplicaciones en que no se abre las consolas y para controlar excepciones:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe","net use \xxx.xxx.x.x /user:{usuario} {contraseña}");
```